# How to cleanly get/copy a remote git branch to local repository

Tags: git

I want an exact "copy" of a remote branch "copied" to a specific local branch.

Say, for example, a team member has created an experimental feature, which he has checked into a branch called `experiment` on the remote repository.  I want to be able to checkout a new branch on my local repository, and "copy" the `experiment` branch, as-is, to my newly checked out branch.

I don't want to merge it with my code - I want to completely overwrite my code so that I can have a clean look at what he's done on the "experiment" branch.

How would one "get" (fetch/pull/whatever...) a remote branch that someone else has committed to the remote repository to your own local repository, in a way that does not try and perform a merge on your own local code?

Comment: I like to keep a separate copy of my local repo for cases like this. Not only does it save you from mistakes, it allows me to work in parallel.

Answer (score 193, accepted):

If you don't care about merging:

```
git reset --hard <remote>/<branch_name>
```

This will exactly do what you want: no merging, no rebasing, simply put the local branch to exactly the same state as the remote is.

In your case however, you don't need that. You want to create a **new** local branch that has the same state as the remote, so specify the remote branch when creating the local one with [`git checkout`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-checkout):

```
git checkout -b <my_new_branch> <remote>/<branch_name>
```

If you want to use the same name locally, you can shorten that to:

```
git checkout <branch_name>
```

You would use [`git reset --hard`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-reset) if you already have a local branch (for example with some changes in it), discard any modifications that *you* made and instead take the exact version of the remote branch.

To be sure that you have the latest state of the remote branch, use [`git fetch <remote>`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-fetch) before either checking out or resetting.

Comment: Don't reset to throw away your changes. Do git stash instead. Way safer.

Comment: This didn't work at first, but that's because I didn't start by fetching the remote.

Comment: I don't understand this answer.  Do you enter "remote/<branch_name>" or "<remote>/<branch_name>" substituting "origin" or something else for <remote>?

Comment: @Robert <remote>/<branch_name>

Comment: i did git checkout -b branchname origin/branchname, but i get warning: refname is ambiguous

Comment: Did not worked for me I tried this `git checkout -b TLA1 origin/TLA1`. `TLA1` is the branch I want created & a branch from my remote repo but I get this.  `fatal: 'https://github.com/myremoterepo/TLA1' is not a commit and a branch 'TLA1' cannot be created from it`

Comment: Check if `git remote` gives you back `origin` as a result. Or run `git fetch` first.

Comment: I was having trouble with this and the reason was that I had copied the branch name from the MR in GitLab, but the actual branch name needed to be further prepended with `origin/`. Bottom line, if this isn't working it may help to run `git branch -r` to see the actual list of remote branch names before doing this.

Answer (score 18):

Suppose `git remote` command outputs `origin` as a result, then

```
git fetch origin remote_branch_name:local_branch_name
```

will create a local branch which is an exact copy of a remote branch you need to.

EDIT:
There is an alternative more modern solution:

```
git switch remote_branch_name
```

the command will create a local branch with the same name as the specified remote branch.

Comment: nothing worked for me but this! Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

I don’t have enough rep to comment, but I’d like to add an example for those still struggling. In my example, I’m using Github as my remote and copying the branch to my Linux server environment/terminal.

First, you’ll want to run `git fetch` To make sure you’re up to date.

Using the example of

`git checkout -b <my_new_branch> <remote>/<branch_name>`

With a remote branch named “picklerick”

I ran

`git checkout -b picklerick remotes/origin/picklerick`

I probably could have just used `remote/picklerick` for my remote path, but this worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Update the local copy of the remote branch with

```
git fetch
```

Create a new branch from the remote branch

```
git branch new_branch_name origin/remote_branch_name
```

here `origin` is the name of your remote.