# How to get remote repo branch added to local repo

Tags: git, github, version-control, branch, git-branch

> newly created - by creating a folder & running the command `git init`
> in short creating a local git repo from the top.

I have here a local git repository (newly created) with **2 branches**. Now these branches are just dummy ones which I created, nothing much important to it.

```
$ git branch
* repo2-branch1
  repo2-branch2
```

I also have here a remote repository (**private**) from Github with a branch **"TLA1"**, now remember the newly created local repository I mentioned above with those 2 branches? What I wanted to do is to **ADD** this **"TLA1"** branch as one of the branches with `repo2-branch1` & `repo2-branch2` in my newly created local repository as I mentioned.

[image]

Let's say the **"TLA1"** branch has been added. So when I type `git branch` I would like to have it like this.

```
$ git branch
* repo2-branch1
  repo2-branch2
  TLA1
```

Of course when I type `git log` when I switch to **"TLA1"** I would also have the commits which is in the remote repository as you can see in the image, cause for me those commits are very important.

### Solutions I have tried:

I have done many research and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11356460/how-to-cleanly-get-copy-a-remote-git-branch-to-local-repository), I thought this was already it as it was similar to my goal. But when I tried it I get an error.

```
$ git checkout -b TLA1 origin/TLA1
fatal: 'origin/TLA1' is not a commit and a branch 'TLA1' cannot be created from it
```

I also have not tried this as this thing might do something to my remote repo `git reset --hard <remote>/<branch_name>` & it seems to be not the solution I am finding.

Any solutions to this? I'd really like to have this branch on my newly created repository.

Comment: `git checkout TLA1`? When you say "newly created", do you mean *cloned*? Does it have any connection to that remote? What does `git branch -la` or `git remote -v` show?

Comment: hello! What I mean by `newly created` I mean is I just created a new folder and have a `git init` there.

Comment: Well why did you do that if you already had a remote? Have you added that remote to the local repo at all?

Comment: as I mentioned on the question, I create a new repository starting from the top then I just wanted to have the "TLA1" branch only as part of that newly created repo along with the dummy branches I made.

Comment: I just wanted to get the "TLA1" branch ONLY & bring it to the local repo I just created... so when I type `git branch` I'll see 3 branches, of course the "TLA1" is now added & of course when I type `git log` when I switch to "TLA1" the commits must also be there cause those commits are indeed important.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'd need to tell Git to track the remote repository first. So you'll have to do

`git remote add origin <url>`

Next you can tell git to only fetch that one branch from remote

`git fetch origin TLA1`

Then you can switch to the branch

`git checkout TLA1`

Comment: Hello @Karthnik! Thanks! I am accepting your answer cause for me it's the most precise one as I can see, my whole life with `git` I've been doing the [`git fetch`](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/syncing/git-fetch#:~:text=In%20review%2C%20git%20fetch%20is,of%20collaborative%20git%20work%20flows.) , since to get commits & meta-data right then `merge` them with a specific branch, but I did not know that you could actually use it to directly `checkout` once you fetch the meta-data on that specific branch. Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

## TL;DR

You will need to run `git fetch origin` before you can run `git checkout TLA1`.

## Long

You are on the right track, but there is a lot to know—and a lot of wrong stuff people pick up that you should be careful of.

#### Things to unlearn

Before you can use Git skillfully, you need to *un*-learn a few things.  These false claims go as follows:

- "Branches matter": this isn't wrong, but this isn't right either.  The first problem is the word *branch*, which is fundamentally ambiguous in Git.  If we stick with the two-word phrase *branch name*, we get something much more useful.  Branch names are important, but only to *humans*.  Git uses them to help us find *commits;* it is the commits that actually matter.
- "Remote branches": this two-word phrase is, if anything, *worse* than the word "branch" by itself.  People use it to mean at least three different things.  Let's avoid this phrase too.  The Git documentation uses the term *remote-tracking branch* or *remote-tracking branch name*, which are the names listed by `git branch -r`.  This phrase is not as bad, but the word *branch* in it is pointless.  Let's just call this a *remote-tracking name*.

#### Things to learn

What matter in Git are the *commits*.  Know these things about commits:

- Each one has a unique hash ID.  The hash ID of some commit means *that* commit.  No other commit—anywhere, in *any* Git repository—will have *that* hash ID.  *That* commit—anywhere, in *any* Git repository—will have *that* hash ID.
- Commits are what get shared, across different Git clones.  The branch names aren't *shared*.  Your Git clone has *your* branch names, and some other clone has *its* branch names.  You probably *want* to use the same names, to keep things straight, but that's up to you (though Git will assist here because that's such a common thing to want).
- Each commit consists of two parts:

  - A commit's main data is a snapshot of all files.  These files are frozen for all time: they are stored in a compressed, read-only, Git-only, and de-duplicated form.  The de-duplication handles the fact that most of the time, most new commits mostly contain the *same* files as the previous commit.  The fact that the files stored inside a commit are frozen and can't even be *read* (much less written) by programs that aren't Git is a problem, of course.
  - The other part of a commit is its *metadata*.  This includes things like the name of the person who made the commit, their email address, and a date-and-time-stamp for *when* they made the commit.  All of this stuff is read-only too.  Crucially for Git itself, Git adds, to this metadata, the hash ID of some *previous* commit or commits.  We call these the *parents* of the commits.

#### Commits form chains; branch names help us (and Git) find the commits

Given that we have some simple sequence of commits:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

where each letter here stands in for an actual Git hash ID, we end up with a linear chain of commits that *ends* with commit `H`.  If we know `H`'s actual hash ID, we can have Git extract this commit (see below).  Or, we can have Git read `H`'s metadata and show us who made the commit ... or use it to find the actual hash ID of `H`'s parent commit `G`.

Since `G` and `H` both hold snapshots, we can have Git compare the two snapshots.  All the files that match are uninteresting, because they match.  Any files that *don't* match are more interesting, and we can have Git figure out what's *different* in them and show us the difference.  That way, we can see what we *changed*.  Git doesn't *store* changes: it just stores snapshots.  But we can see a snapshot *as* changes, because a commit has a parent.

We can have Git go back to `G`, too and use that to find `F`, and hence to view `G` as changes.  From there, we can go back to `F`, and use that to find a still earlier commit, and so on.  But to do all this, we need the actual hash ID of the *last* commit in the chain.  This is where branch names come in: a branch name like `repo-branch1` just stores some hash ID.  The hash ID stored in the name is, by definition, the *last* commit in the branch.  Git will start there and work backwards.  It doesn't matter if there are later commits *after* that point either:

```
...--E--F   <-- br1
         \
          G--H   <-- br2
```

Here `H` is the *last* commit (after `F` and `G` for instance) in `br2`, while commit `F` is the *last* commit in `br1`.  Commits up through `F` are in *both branches*, but `br1` starts-or-ends (depending on how you look at it) at `F` and works backwards, while `br2` ends at `H` and works backwards.

#### Extracted commits

Because commits are read-only, we can't actually work on or with them directly.  We have to pick some commit and make it the *current commit*.  When we do that, Git *extracts* all the files that go with that commit into a work area, which Git calls the *working tree* or *work-tree*.  These are the files you can see and work with.  They're ordinary everyday computer files, that every program on your computer can use.  But they're not actually *in* Git.

We run:

```
git checkout br2
```

(or `git switch br2` in Git 2.23 or later).  Git uses the name `br2` to find the last (or *tip*) commit of that branch (note ambiguous word, in this case meaning some set of commits ending at `H`).  Git then extracts the files from that commit, so that we can see and work with them, and makes that commit the *current commit* while making that branch name the *current branch*.  I like to draw that like this:

```
...--E--F   <-- br1
         \
          G--H   <-- br2 (HEAD)
```

The special name `HEAD` is *attached to* a branch name.  This is what it means to be "on the branch": that the name `HEAD` locates the branch name `br2`.  The branch name itself locates the commit, `H`, which is the one Git extracted.

If we make a *new* commit, Git will package up a snapshot, add the metadata, set the *parent* of the new commit to be the *current* commit `H`, and use all of that to write out the new commit.  This assigns the commit its new, big ugly random-looking—but not actually random at all—hash ID, which I'll just call `I`.  Since `I`'s parent is `H`, `I` points back to `H`.  Then Git simply writes `I`'s hash ID into the current *name*, `br2`, giving:

```
...--E--F   <-- br1
         \
          G--H--I   <-- br2 (HEAD)
```

Hence the special feature of a *branch name* is that it *automatically moves to point to a new commit when we make it*.  Git accomplishes this by attaching the name `HEAD` to the branch name.

Git has other names—such as tag names and remote-tracking names—that *also* point to commits (by storing commit hash IDs), but you can't attach `HEAD` to them.

#### Remote-tracking names and `git fetch`

Remote-tracking names have forms like `origin/TLA1`: they start with a *remote name* like `origin`.  The remote name is the one you use when you use `git remote add`; `origin` is simply the first *standard* one.  If you use `git clone` to run `git init` and `git remote add` and so on for you, `git clone` will use `origin` as the standard first remote name.  **Note: You didn't use `git clone` so the name will be up to you when you run `git remote add`.**

As noted above, you can't attach `HEAD` to a remote-tracking name.  Moreover, you normally don't create these names yourself.  You can use `git branch -r` to list out the ones you have right now, but if *you* don't create them, how do you get them?

The answer to that last question is that the `git fetch` command creates them.  The fetch command is tremendously complicated (for reasons both good and bad) and I definitely won't cover very much of it here, but we can describe it relatively simply like this: `git fetch` has your Git call up some other Git and get stuff from it:

- First, your Git has their Git list out all of their branch names, tag names, and other such names.  These come with hash IDs—mostly commit hash IDs, though tag names get a little more complicated sometimes.
- Then your Git picks through these names and hash IDs.  You Git can tell whether you have the commits, because every Git uses the *same random-looking-but-not-random hash IDs* for the same commits.  So your Git immediately knows if you have the tip commits of *their* branches.

  If you don't, your Git asks their Git for their commits.  They offer the commit's parents too, and your Git checks to see if you have *those* commits.  Through this kind of have/want sequence (with some important optimizations that avoid having to list every hash ID every time), your Git figures out what commits they have, that you don't, that you'll need, and asks for them.
- They they package up all these commits and send them to you.  The details here can vary a lot, but in the usual case you see "counting" and "compressing" and so on, and then your Git receives a package full of commits and other internal Git objects.  Your Git then saves this all away in your repository.

  You now have all of the commits you had before, *plus* any commits they had that you didn't (unless your Git doesn't want them, e.g., single-branch clones).
- Last, your Git now *creates or updates your remote-tracking names*.  For every *branch* name they have, your Git creates or updates the corresponding remote-tracking name for your repository.

**What this means is that you never get their branch names directly.  You get their branch names and *change them* into your remote-tracking names.  This acts as your Git's *memory* of their branch names.  These are created or updated by `git fetch`.**  Until you run `git fetch`, you won't *have* an `origin/TLA1`.

#### Conclusion

It's the *commits* that matter.  Branch names and other names help you (and Git) *find* commits.

You get your remote-tracking names by running `git fetch`.  You tell `git fetch` which *remote* to call up.  Your Git calls up that remote and sees its branches and gets its commits, unless you already have them.  Then your Git updates or creates the remote-tracking names as needed.  (Side note: your Git won't *delete* a "dead" name here unless you tell it to, so once they delete some branch name, you'll be left with stale remote-tracking names.)

You can create your own branch names at any time, but to create a name, you must have a *commit* for it to point-to.  So you'll generally want to get their latest ones first: `git fetch`, *then* some second Git command.

Aside: `git pull` means *run `git fetch`, then run a second Git command*.  Since it takes the two commands to do useful stuff, people like `git pull`, which runs the two commands.  I dislike `git pull` because I like to insert commands *between* these two, and maybe use something other than the relatively thin set of choices that `git pull` offers for the second command, but that's up to you.

Comment: Hello @torek , first of all I appreciate your answer as it is super detailed which is awesome!  You provided a lot of details with just a simple question that I had which is I am thankful for, but I think I have to accept the @Karthik's answer as it is short and solves my issue but please keep your answer as it will be useful to other people as well... I'll I'm making your answer as one of my notes in studying further with `git` Thanks a lot! really appreciate it!

Comment: Thanks for this if I could only check all the answers since they all satisfy my concern! Going to make this as one of my ultimate guide's with git :)

Comment: Nice writeup, @torek. If you ever write a book on git please add me to the advance purchase list!

Answer (score 1):

Add the remote to your local repository then fetch from it.

```
git remote add REMOTE_NAME REMOTE_URL
git fetch REMOTE_NAME
git checkout -b branch_name REMOTE_NAME/branch_name
```

The last command creates a local branch from the remote ref.

Then git branch should show:

```
git branch

LOCAL1
LOCAL2
branch_name
```

Comment: Hello @Ouss4, Thank you so much! your solution is the same as @Karthik , but to be honest for me in my case it is not needed to do a `git fetch REMOTE_NAME`. Instead a better way of doing it is `git fetch REMOTE_NAME BRANCH_NAME` , since I am focusing on one branch only. But your answer is 100% great! Please keep it as other people who might have similar problems that might find your solution as their solution. Thank you :D

Comment: Thanks for this! This works also, but I have a lot of branches in my repo I think it's not necessary to fetch the whole repo but still I believe this answer would be relevant to other people who might see it so thanks for adding this.